# Always getting wrong radio button value. What's wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is a live example of my problem

http://jsfiddle.net/littlesandra88/xksB9/

I would have expected that the "Create" button returned an empty string, when its radio buttons are not selected. Instead it reads the value from the radio buttons from the form below.

The bottom "Save" button always returns the value from the form above. Very strange!

Here is the code

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $('form').live('submit', function(){

      var title      = this.elements.title.value;
      var owner      = this.elements.owner.value;

      var type = $('input:radio[name=ctype]:checked').val() || '';

      alert(type);

    });
});
```

The idea is, I will auto-generate forms of the type at the bottom, and so don't know the ID's before hand, so I just give them random numbers to make them unique.

How can this problem be solved?

Comment: My version of chrome treats your example HTML very strangely. I think you should either put your table inside your form, and/or your forms inside `td`s - interlacing the form and table as you are doing causes my browser to prematurely and automatically terminate your form DOM elements leaving the radio buttons outside the forms.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may want to just change this line:

```
var type = $('input:radio[name=ctype]:checked').val() || '';
```

to

```
var type = $('#create_form input:radio[name=ctype]:checked').val() || '';
```

So that jQuery only looks in the top form, rather than in whole DOM.

Not sure what the overall goal is, but that edit at least gets you the behavior you're looking for.

If you want the individual save buttons to function in a similar way, change it to:

```
var type = $(this).find('input:radio[name=ctype]:checked').val() || '';
```

**EDIT**

To get the other forms to work, you need to change the HTML a bit so that the form tags wrap the tables, and not the other way around. This is what I changed each for to (notice that this would make multiple tables instead of one table):

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <input name="anchor" value="54" type="hidden">
  <table class="alerts" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
      <tr>                                
        <td class="activity-data">54</td>
        <td class="activity-data"> <input name="title" id="54_title" value="" type="text" /> </td>
        <td class="activity-data"> <input name="owner" id="54_owner" value="" type="text" /> </td>          
        <td class="activity-data"> <input name="ctype" value="individuel" type="radio" checked/> Individuel <br> <input name="ctype" value="course" type="radio" /> Course </td>
        <td> <input value="Save" type="submit" /></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```

This way, the radio buttons are proper children of the forms and jQuery is happy about that.

Comment: But I would like that the Save buttons returns the value from their radio bottons.

Comment: Yes, I would very much like each button return the value from their radio buttons. When I try your last code, it works for the top form, but not for the forms below.

Comment: Oh right, I needed to fix the HTML -- added that edit to the answer.

Comment: Very impressive! How did you figure out that it was a child problem?

Comment: Thanks! I realized it was a child problem when **$(this).find('input:radio[name=ctype]:checked').length** was returning 0, which clearly wasn't right...

Answer (score 2):

Each group of radio buttons should probably have their own matching names, because it looks like the form treats them as separate groups. For instance, your first group of radio buttons might have the name `foo`:

```
<input name="foo" id="ctype" value="individuel" type="radio" /> Individuel <br/>
<input name="foo" id="ctypee" value="course"    type="radio" /> Course <br/>
```

Now these radio buttons are a part of the same radio group, and the others are a part of another group (although they should be named different from each other as well). Now you can safely grab the value from the `foo` radio group:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $('form').live('submit', function(){

      var title      = this.elements.title.value;
      var owner      = this.elements.owner.value;

      // looking for 'foo' radio button group selection
      var type = $('input:radio[name=foo]:checked').val() || '';

      alert(type); // alerts the correct selection from the top form
    });
});
```

Comment: Just spreading the word: [Attribute values in selector expressions must be surrounded by quotation marks.](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/)

Comment: But the problem is, that I must be able to auto-generate many 400 forms, so I can't know the names or IDs in advance.

Comment: Alternatively, you can keep the names the same and search directly below a particular form by specifying it's ID and using the `find()` method: `var type = $('#create_form').find('input:radio[name=ctype]:checked').val() || '';`

Comment: @Sandra - Yeah then it might be more difficult to scale my solution. I suppose you could add ids to the names. For instance, you could generate names for the 400 forms like `name="foo-0"` ... `name="foo-399"`, but you'd have to add extra code to hook that all up. Andy and _rusty's solutions are good options as well. Just be aware that the similar names could be a potential bug source if anything goes wrong.

Comment: @Andy E - Yeah that's a good solution too. People just need to be cautious to grab the right form.

Comment: @Mully - It's funny that you mention that, because I thought that was always the case too. But I remember seeing this exact example on the jQuery API without quotations, and I was sufficiently confused. I'll try to find the example page.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at this line:

```
<input name="ctype" value="individuel" type="radio" checked/>
```

you can see that you've included a 'checked' attribute in there. Remove it to solve your issue around having the 'individuel' returned when there are no selections.

Oh, and if you want to pre-select a value, it's supposed to be

```
<input name="ctype" value="individuel" type="radio" checked="checked" />
```

**NOTE:** This is just to add to what others have said already.

Comment: The two forms at the bottom must have pre-selected values. The top form should not have pre-selected. I think you pasted the same line twice?

Comment: That looks a lot better. Thanks.